python giving AttributeError
this is my problem :
class Student :
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def __print(self):
        print(self.name)
st = Student("amir")
st.__print()


My platform is Windows 10
I used IDE VS Code


I was defining an object called Student for my class and I wanted to define the print method for this object as private, but I cannot call this method and when executing the command, Python gives me AttributeError.

You can't call private methods from outside the class. That's what makes them private.

Also, self.name should be self.__name (or vice versa).

Why do you think your class needs its own method for printing? You should define a __str__() method, then the print() function will call it automatically.

Don't use name mangling.

Atribute names that begin with __ are special.  Don't do that unless you know what you're doing.

@mohammad saleh. You are using older Python 3.8 version. It worked for me using Python 3.12.7. I suggest to update Python 3.13.0  this October 10th. It is bug free.

Python doesn't enforce any notion of privacy in the way C++ and Java do. A __-prefixed name is to prevent accidental shadowing of variables. They are still accessible with a tiny bit of work.
>>> st._Student__print()
amir

If you want to mark something as not private, but not part of the public interface (meaning, you can but shouldn't use it), a single _ is conventional.
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    def _print(self):
        print(self._name)

st = Student("amir")
st._print()  # Still works, but it's meant to be used publicly, just name it "print"


I identified two errors in your code:
In the __print() method, you are calling the self.name attribute, but you defined it in the initialization as self.__name.
The other error is that the __print() method is private, that is, it should not be called outside the class itself.
I made a version of your code that corrects the call by the self.__name attribute and keeps the private __print() method, which is called by a new method called show_name().
class Student :
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name

    def __print(self):
        print(self.__name)
    
    def show_name(self):
        self.__print()

st = Student("amir")
st.show_name()


Neither are private; __-prefixed names invoke name mangling to avoid accidental shadowing. st._Student__print() would work fine.

@chepner The [documentation] refers to this as private. It's like a lock on a door -- it's not impossible to pick, but it's good enough.
